# XQuery/XPath - Joining two sets of elements on attributes with values in common

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

basis XML:

```
<people>
    <person uname="mark">Mark</person>
    <person uname="ryan">Ryan</person>
    <person uname="anna">Anna</person>
</people>
<dogs>
    <canine owner="mark">Lucy</canine>
    <canine owner="anna">Joey</canine>
</dogs>
```

Desired result:

```
Mark
Anna
```

I've just begun learning XPath and XQuery. Can this be done using XPath only, or do I need XQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be done with XPath alone. The thing to remember is that `=` effectively does a join:

```
//person[@uname=//dogs/canine/@owner]/text()
```

Comment: I'm astonished how powerful XPath can be.. (and thank you for rephrasing the title of my question)